# error code=H10: Unable to deploy springboot app to heroku

Tags: python, java, spring-boot, heroku

I am really new to springboot and I buld my first rest API and wanted to deploy it to heroku. But unfortunately the heroku returned `at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"` error. Here is my procfile

```
web: java -jar target/Destadeals.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here is pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>Destadeals</groupId>
    <artifactId>Destadeals</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Destadeals</name>
    <description>Desta deals project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sebastian-daschner</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-analyzer</artifactId>
            <version>0.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/desta_deals?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= password

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
# App Properties
bezkoder.app.jwtSecret= loginaccepted
bezkoder.app.jwtExpirationMs= 86400000
server.port=${PORT:8080}
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui-custom.html
```

I have tried the following procfile

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/Destadeals.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/Destadeals.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

web: java -jar target/java-getting-started-1.0.jar
```

But none of the above procfile codes worked for me.

Here is log file after running `heroku logs --tail -a desta-deals-backend`

```
2022-03-21T08:35:05.982432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=desta-deals-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=d2b8c3a0-977d-4b5b-bfc3-33019714901c fwd="196.190.152.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-21T08:35:06.652854+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=desta-deals-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=5ecb9bde-d9df-4763-997f-b25d82f76614 fwd="196.190.152.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

What can I change to deploy my springboot application to heroku?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your application is actually being packaged into a `jar`, i.e. the file `target/Destadeals.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` actually exists in your project folder after building with `mvn clean install`.

It would be helpful if you could also provide a log tail of your Heroku dyno. There could be plenty of reasons for your app crashing. To get a log tail, you  may call `heroku logs --tail -a <app-name>`. A thing to look out for is your database: I see it being configured as a local instance (`localhost:3306`) but this will of course not work on your Heroku dyno.

Comment: I added log file. Thanks